# Jquery on('click) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several div elements which are populated with an index e.g.

```
Divid1 + index0
Divid2 + index1
Divid3 + index2
```

A click function has been applied to these individual elements so Jquery SlideToggle could open the div elements that have been assigned to these.

Now I have created a on click function for an image to open these boxes using the trigger function however it doesn't seem to work.

```
$('image').on('click', function () {
   $('#result' + index).trigger('click');
});
```

I want this to enable the click event that have been assigned:

```
$('#result'+index).click(function({  
   $(this).next("#nesteddiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is `index` set, and what is its value? It looks like using a common class and a single event handler would be a much better idea.

Comment: Please add this to a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know any `image` tag, it should be `img` . Also `id` must be unique and your code `$(this).next("#nesteddiv")` tell that you might be using it more than once

Comment: image must have an ID or class, use #image or .image

Comment: adding to @RohitTiwari ans, if it is Image Element then change to `img` not image.

Comment: Is this remotely close to something you want? https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/aq1j8cLx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to slideToggle an element adjacent to the one clicked a CSS selector with a wildcard would be most appropriate.

```
$('.slideToggleImage').on('click', function () {
    $("[id^=result]").trigger('click');
});

$("[id^=result]").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".nesteddiv").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

And change the #nesteddiv to a class since an ID should always be unique. It would work, but it's just best practice :)

Comment: You're more than welcome! I often forget about the wildcard selectors' existence and usefulness myself ;-) Don't forget to mark this as a working answer. Happy coding!

Comment: I have a quick question , how do I make this work for unique div elements and not enable the toggle for all DIV elements? Again thank you :)

Comment: It should only fire on elements with an id that starts with `result`. Then it searches for a sibling with a class of `nesteddiv` and slides that down or up. You may no to structure your HTML if it fires for all divs. But since you didn't provide any I can't help you there :)